# How do I make this python code output 0 1 4 6

Tags: python

```
print(matrix)
    #matrix is [2,2,[0,1],[4,6]]
    matrix = list(matrix)
    rownum = matrix[0]
    colnum = matrix[1]
    del matrix[1], matrix[0]
    print(colnum)
    print(rownum)
    print(matrix)
    #matrix is now [[0,1], [4,6]]

    matrixfile = open(outfilehandle, "w")
    matrixfile.write(name)
    for colnum in range(colnum):
        matrixfile.writelines("\n"+"\t")
        for rownum in range(rownum):
            output = matrix[colnum][rownum]
            print(output)
            #output is: 0   1   4
```

Above is a function that I want to output as a matrix. Ignore the writing code as I am just trying to get a proper output before writing to a file. The current output seems like it is missing the last value in the matrix list. I want it to output: 0 1 4 6 but it is only outputting: 0 1 4

Comment: `for rownum in range(rownum)` overwrites `rownum`. Choose a different variable name.

Comment: When I try and "save" the rownum value (2) to another variable then use that new variable as the range, my command line shows an error that int object is not callable. However if I just use the value 2 instead of a variable it works properly, but the range will vary with the number of rows so I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because iterator is overwriting actual variable name, so that's why it's not working, so maybe:

```
for colnum_ in range(colnum):
  matrixfile.writelines("\n"+"\t")
  for rownum_ in range(rownum):
      output = matrix[colnum_][rownum_]
      print(output)
```

For that part.

Comment: Thank you sir this is exactly what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity how does adding an underscore to a variable work? Earlier when I was trying to solve this I would try making range = rownum then using the range variable for range, however I was getting an error that int object is not callable.

Comment: Good that you received your answer. Please go through the guidelines on how to ask the question and please provide the output that you expect to see. That helps a lot to provide the right answer. Cheers

Comment: @GrilledSqueeze Happy to help, underscore variables don't matter here, you can actually name the iterator `blahbalhablah` if you want, it can be anything, btw. please accept if it works :-), 

Answer (score 0):

When you do the for loops, you're changing the values of the variables `colnum` and `rownum`.  After you have looped through `for rownum in range(rownum):` the first time, `rownum` has been changed to 1.  You should use different variables for the indices, for example:

```
for col in range(colnum):
    matrixfile.writelines("\n"+"\t")
    for row in range(rownum):
        output = matrix[col][row]
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a little bit vague as the reader does not know if your intent is to pick up any of the double elements..

If its just to get the output that you want then the code is very simple

```
from itertools import chain
matrix=[2,2,[0,1],[4,6]]        
print(list(chain(*matrix[2:4])))
```

Comment: He want's to output in text file tho.

Comment: Oh.. now I understood.. he has the matrix where the dimensions of the matrix are provided in first 2 elements... while later elements define the whole matrix. Probably now he wants it to print like a matrix on a text file.

Comment: I am afraid U9 is right and I am also only allowed to use built in python tools. I appreciate the answer though, definitely a solution I will check out in other circumstances.

Comment: No problem.. we are all here to help.